# InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for {!r}".format(url))

Tags: python-3.x, ajax, beautifulsoup, python-requests, http-post

What does this error means and how to address this kind of error?I am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "load-more.py", line 146, in <module>
    response = session.get(link)
File "C:\Users\Xone\.virtualenvs\Web_Scrapers-A6P4QRzc\lib\site-packages\requests \sessions.py", line 555, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Xone\.virtualenvs\Web_Scrapers-A6P4QRzc\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Xone\.virtualenvs\Web_Scrapers-A6P4QRzc\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 649, in send
    adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)
File "C:\Users\Xone\.virtualenvs\Web_Scrapers-A6P4QRzc\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 742, in get_adapter
   raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for {!r}".format(url))
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '\\"https:\\/\\/lifebridgecapital.com\\/2021\\/06\\/11\\/ws964-multifamily-investing-is-a-team-sport-with-cameron-roy\\/\\"'
```

when I try to parse the links for title.I am trying to scrape with requests post method here is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

 headers = {
     'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0',
     'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
     'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
     'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
     'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
     'Origin': 'https://lifebridgecapital.com',
     'Connection': 'keep-alive',
     'Referer': 'https://lifebridgecapital.com/podcast/',
     'Sec-GPC': '1',
     'TE': 'Trailers',
  }

 data = {'action': 'gdlr_core_post_ajax', 
'settings[category][]': 'podcast', 
'settings[tag]': '', 'settings[num-fetch]': '9',
'settings[paged]': '1', 
'option[name]': 'paged', 

 }

 session = requests.Session()

for page in range(0, 55):
    data['option[value]'] = str(page + 1)
    response = session.post('https://lifebridgecapital.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', headers=headers, data=data)
    links = [a['href'] for a in BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml').select('h3 > a')]
    for link in links:
        response = session.get(link)
        page = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
        title = page.find('h3').text
        print(f'Title: {title}, Link: {link}')


        #print(f'title: {title}, links: {links}')
```

I am getting all the links but when try to parse that link for title this Invalid Schema error occurs I searched alot on google before asking here at SO but didn't get the solution or answer to why this error occurring .

Answer (score 0):

You get a JSON-response and the html is in `content`. So you cannot directly use Beautiful Soup with `response.text`.

Replace `response.text` with `response.json()['content']`.

```
links = [a['href'] for a in BeautifulSoup(response.json()['content'], 'lxml').select('h3 > a')]
```

Comment: Error is gone but links are duplicating.Any idea,why?

Comment: You can use a set instead of a list to eliminate duplicates: `links = {a['href'] for a in BeautifulSoup(response.json()['content'], 'lxml').select('h3 > a')}`